# ¿Cómo aumentar la velocidad de compilación del Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy desarrollando para Android y he notado que la velocidad de Build de mi Gradle es extremadamente lenta, así que me gustaría saber cómo aumentar la velocidad de Build de Gradle?

¿Qué configuraciones utilizar en Android Studio?

> Estoy usando **Gradle** versión **3.3**.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, si, estás en lo correcto android-studio mejoró la optimización del gradle, de todas formas si no quieres cambiar de versión aquí te dejo una documentación de como mejorar la velocidad del `build gradle`[consejos para mejorar la velocidad](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/10-tips-to-improve-your-gradle-build-time-1ddeca924759)